# Beautiful logical minimum construction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, logic

On a circle after equal intervals 25 points are located. On every point is a policeman.

All policemen are numbered (from 1 to 25) in some way. Now they have to move to some other points through this circle, in a way that after moving they will be sequentially numbered clockwise.

Take such a movement that the sum of all distances covered by the policemen is minimal. Prove that in this movement someone remained on his point.

I proved the case for 3 points (3 policemen), and I assume that by induction we have to show for all numbers (or all odd numbers?), but couldn't do it for a long time. How is it proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $N$ points, where $N$ is odd, and suppose that all policemen moves. Let $L$ be the number of policemen that moves to the left, and $R$ be the number of policemen that moves to the right. Without loss of generality, let $L < R$  (since $N$ is odd). Consider the solution in which all policemen who moves right moves one step less, and all policemen who moves left moves one step more. The positions relative to each other policemen in this case remain the same, but the sum of distances decrease -- hence, the solution is not optimal = a contradiction.